# VS code, python and quarto file rendering problem

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions, quarto

````
---
title: "Quarto Basics"
format:
  html:
    code-fold: true
jupyter: python3
---

For a demonstration of a line plot on a polar axis, see @fig-polar.

```{python}
#| label: fig-polar
#| fig-cap: "A line plot on a polar axis"

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r
fig, ax = plt.subplots(
  subplot_kw = {'projection': 'polar'} 
)
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax.set_rticks([0.5, 1, 1.5, 2])
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```
````

```
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\trial> quarto preview c:/Users/HP/Desktop/trial/demo_1.qmd --no-browser --no-watch-inputs
```

```
ERROR: The file cannot be accessed by the system. (os error 1920): stat 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe'

Stack trace:

    at Object.statSync (ext:deno_fs/30_fs.js:363:7)
    at existsSync (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:495:27)
    at getQuartoJupyterCapabilities (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:30574:13)
    at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:183:11)
    at async jupyterCapabilities (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:30489:28)
    at async pythonExec (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:30669:18)
    at async Object.execute (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:38357:29)
    at async renderExecute (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:76994:27)
    at async renderFileInternal (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:77176:43)
    at async renderFiles (file:///C:/Program%20Files/Quarto/bin/quarto.js:77044:17) PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\trial>
```

I have uninstalled and re-installed several times but it giving me the same error.

How can I solve the following error?

**What I want to do**: I want to run the quarto document in vs code. I have installed Quarto extension for vs code (`v1.110.1`) and also installed Quarto CLI (`v1.4.542`). I want to have the file in HTML format. I am using windows 10.

**Problem:** When I run the qmd file, it gives the following error.

Comment: Reformat your question by using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use the following guide [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/7414#discussioncomment-7576354)

Comment: Also try to follow these general recommendations [here](https://quarto.org/docs/troubleshooting/).

Comment: Finally improve the wording because the question asked is confusing. Apparently, you are trying to run the following code: https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/hello/vscode.html#render-and-preview. So specify better this aspect and point out that you can not run this example.

Comment: After @shafee's revision of the question, I now have a better grasp of your query. Could you please navigate to the C:\Users\HP\Desktop\trial directory, right-click in an empty area within this folder, and choose "Open PowerShell window here"? Once the PowerShell window opens, enter the command `quarto check` and share with us the section that pertains to "Checking Python 3 Installation". It seems that Windows is attempting to default to a Python installation from the Microsoft App Store, particularly noticeable in the reference to 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe'.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).